# Area chart Series

Tags: java, jfreechart

I think my question is a little silly, but I couldn't find the answer in the examples!

I create a area chart and I need to change the name of the series, in the legend of the graph

here:

```
final CategoryDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset(
    "Series ", "Type ", data
);
```

When a put "Series", it appears in the legend, something like this: Series 1, Series 2, Series 3.....

Is it possible to change their names, and each one has a different name?

Comment: You don't _have_ to use that utility class to create the dataset. See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo.htm) which manually builds up a `DefaultCategoryDataset`

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116600&p=176694).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DatasetUtilities` API is [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DatasetUtilities.html). Looking at `createCategoryDataset()`,

```
public static CategoryDataset createCategoryDataset(
    java.lang.Comparable[] rowKeys,
    java.lang.Comparable[] columnKeys,
    double[][] data)
```

note in particular,

> Row and column keys are taken from the supplied arrays.

It looks like you can just pass in an array of the values that you want.